# How to run background the project Django, use gunicorn?

Tags: python, django, web-deployment-project, gunicorn

I use gunicorn to deploy project Django background.

```
python2.7 manage.py run_gunicorn 0.0.0.0:8090
```

It is not run background.

```
gunicorn_django -b 0.0.0.0:8090
```

It doesn't see the my apps.

The project ran successfully when `python manage.py runserver`

Answer (score 0):

To run gunicorn in background you will need to use a process control system like [Supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) to manage gunicorn.

Deployment instructions with Supervisor and/or Runit are described [here](http://gunicorn.org/deploy.html)

For the part of problem where the apps are not detected, did you add `gunicorn` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting in django `settings.py`? If not integration is decribed [here](http://gunicorn.org/run.html#django-manage-py)

Edit:

Sample gunicorn management script for supervisor

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
    LOGFILE=/home/ubuntu/logs/gunicorn/x.log
    LOGDIR=$(dirname $LOGFILE)
    NUM_WORKERS=3
    HOST=0.0.0.0:8000
    # user/group to run as
    USER=ubuntu
    GROUP=ubuntu
    cd ~/webapps/Z/
    . ~/virtualenvs/production/bin/activate
    test -d $LOGDIR || mkdir -p $LOGDIR
    exec ~/virtualenvs/production/bin/gunicorn_django -b $HOST -w $NUM_WORKERS \
        --user=$USER --group=$GROUP --log-level=debug \
        --log-file=$LOGFILE 2>>$LOGFILE
```

Comment: I installed ang ran supervisor.
When i ran `python2.7 manage.py run_gunicorn 0.0.0.0:8090 - w 2 --preload --daemon  --user=htk --group=htk --log-level=debug --log-file=/home/htk/workspace/testproject/testproject.log 2>>/home/htk/workspace/testproject/testproject.log`

It logged: `Error: Usage is runserver [optional port number, or ipaddr:port or unix:/path/to/sockfile]`

Comment: Your usage is incorrect, run `gunicorn_django` directly without the `python manage.py`